# How can I react to an acne, without getting any marks on my face?

Tags: cleaning, personal-care

**Background:** In some days there are something like "acne" on my face. Actually I  don't know is it acne or pimples (I don't know the difference between them). It is something that rises from the skin and after few days, its tip will become yellowish. Inside of it there will be a yellowish liquid and also a yellowish material. 
And this cause to make black marks if I ignore it, or there would be scares if I try to remove it.

**Question:** How can I react to such thing( I call it acne, but I don't know whether is it an acne or pimple or something else), without getting any marks on face in future?

**How I try to *hacking* it:** I suppose they may be the older stage(or the *adult version*) of whiteheads that appears in the skin. And I try to remove all whiteheads as best as I can, at their primary stage. But this method even doesn't give me a good result.

Comment: See also close reason on http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/how-to-prevent-acne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to deal with acne is to stop it before it starts. Once it does you just have to ride it out. Getting stressed about it makes it worse as does physically aggravating it. Drink lots of water and use a cleanser with salicylic acid at least once a day, maybe twice. It's a good treatment, but it can dry out your face so applying moisturizer/sunscreen is a good move as well.

Comment: Are there any at-home remedies (anything that most people have at home that they may not need to purchase)?

Comment: Frankly none that I can think of. But like I said hydration is a big thing so keeping water close makes a big difference.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should go to a doctor for some advice or for some prescription treatment. If you feel that the doctor's method is not very effective and you are left on your own, I suggest trying some skin care product. I used to be troubled by acne/pimples, and I've tried a lot of different brands of cleanser, blemish treatments like Neutrogena or Murad, etc. Finally the brand that worked for me is Juice Beauty. They are organic and natural, nontoxic. Different people have skin that react differently to those skin care products, so you can't be sure how effective it's going to be until you give it a try. 
Usually, it comes in three steps:
1. Cleanse
2. Treat
3. Moisturize
If you are totally clueless to how to get started, I would say start with cleanse and moisturize while you are figuring out which treatment product works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

Usually squeezing spots is the best option but in cases of severe acne it's not that simple as you can end up with long term scars. The best option is simply to see a dermatologist, they will be able to provide you with the best information and treatment to clear the acne up. The earlier, the better. Acne usually develops from a build up of oil and bacteria in the skin, so try to use oil-free face wash etc and wash you face 2 or 3 times each day

Answer (score 0):

In my Case, Skin Care Products didn't made my skin better. But cleaning the skin with water and pealing is a good thing to avoid acne. My Solution is based on a healthy nutrition. I made the experience, that my acne increases when my body try to get rid of "bad" substances (fat, alcohol etc.) and my disgestion didn't work very well. So i try to eat vegetables with every meal and chew them quiet well to support my digestion. additionally I use healing earth before i go to bed (this binds toxic substances). I support my liver by ingesting holy thistle pill (I translated that from German "Mariendistel"- hope its correct) after greasy meals. Good luck with your acne or pimple.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have acne. It might be something similar such as rosacea.
Here are some skin conditions often confused with acne:

[Acne look alikes](https://www.verywell.com/acne-look-alikes-15614/)

While what you eat has more to do with your general health than what you eat specifically, here are a few things associated with skin eruptions.

Excessive Sugar intake will push your body to produce insulin. Cut back on simple carbohydrates and sweet drinks and snacks.

Try cutting Dairy. Supplement your calcium with green leafy veggies. If that works, try introducing a little non-sweetened yogurt from cows or from other animals such as goat. See how that goes.

Oils and Fats can be a problem. Corn, safflower, and canola oil can be problematic. Increase fish rich in omega-3s such as salmon and mackerel.

It's trendy to look at gluten even if you don't have celiac disease. A lot of nutritious foods have gluten including whole wheat bread. Chat with a nutritionist about the pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution for that one pimple that pops up, put a dab of toothpaste on it before going to bed, by morning it should be well on its way to healing.Not gel toothpaste , but pasty paste. This is not for a face full of pimples, just an occasional one.