# How to prevent acne?

Tags: personal-care

Acne is very common for teenagers, and it is painful and very annoying, due to the skin rash.
**How can I prevent it, even if it's extremly common and usual?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to be simple, you could just wash your face often—I'd say once or twice a day, and be consistent.

It works after a while, albeit taking longer than it really should if you use a cream for the same purpose.

Comment: I would add that you should do it with cold water, which closes pores and prevents irritants from getting in your skin and causing this problem and others. I had occasional acne and tried cold water showers/face wash and it noticeably reduced frequency, severity and longevity of zits and other breakouts. This did not completely eliminate the problem, but it did help.

Comment: One could also try to stop eating sugar and processed foods